# Activities with only one fragment.. why?

Tags: android, android-fragments

At my work project, the senior android developer has designed the code structure to have every screen as a fragment, however every fragment has its own activity that it sits in. The activity does nothing else but hold its respective Fragment. To me this doesn't really make sense.

One time I implemented a feature that contained 4 screens using the following pattern, when i first started work on this project:
Activity A : Fragment A (Screen 1), Fragment B (Screen 2), Fragment C (Screen 3), Fragment D (Screen 4) working in that flow navigating from A-B-C-D, so I would be replacing the fragments within Activity A

The senior dev had me refactor the code to make it as following:
Activity A with Fragment A -> Activity B with Fragment B -> ..etc

I asked him why is this approach better than the one i implemented. His reasoning was that it is more modular if in future the app is to be ported on a tablet and that fragment back stack manager is buggy and not easy to use for backward navigation. I didn't really quite understand his explanation for why its better, because popupbackstack seems to work fine. To me its lot more cleaner to have 1 Activity for a specific feature of the app, and swap all the related screens for that feature (fragment) in and out within the activity.

I am also starting to work on a personal android app, and before I do I want to know which really is the correct way to do this. And if there is no correct way, what are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: That senior developer has given you the excuse for "[speculative generality](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/speculative-generality)". Do whatever works best for you

Comment: Sadly I can't do what works best for me, both approaches are simple to implement. I just wanted to know if one way more cleaner, efficient, etc.. And we already have all the features following the senior dev's suggested pattern and I don't want to deviate from that just for the features I work on and have inconsistency. also we are so far into the project now with deadline approaching, i can't go back and refactor all the features.

Comment: In any case, both approaches will work, but obviously starting new Activities, you need to concerned with passing around Intent extras between the Activity and also passing those extras into the Fragment arguments. Seems messy when you could just replace the Fragment in one Activity with the new Arguments

Comment: It's time the old man retires. The approch and reason he gave do not make sense. I would fire him if he continued with such stories. :-).

Comment: @greenapps can you give actual reasoning as to why one approach is better than the other?

Comment: Your reasoning was ok. Thats all.

Comment: yes here your way is good.just use one activity for all fragment then that's good.if you want example then tell me i will provide

Comment: @SachinSuthar yes an example would be very helpful

Comment: @yellowmonkey : there is large code for this so here i suggest link and check that.

Comment: Personally I do custom viewgroups and only 1 activity, no fragments, and a custom backstack.